# Why laptop touchpad "tap" and touchpad button "click" breaks .hover() on Chrome, but with PC mouse all works fine?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I have a problem when I "tap" on laptop touchpad or 'click' with LMB touchpad over html element thats have a jquery .hover() or in javascript events (mouseenter, mouseleave). After touchpad tap or click hover breaks.

HTML:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
  <div id="containerLeft">
    <h1>div1</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="containerRight">
    <h1>div2</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#containerRight').hover(function(e){
  $(this).stop().animate({width: '80%',  margin: "0 0 0 -500px", zIndex: '1000'},150);
}, function(e) {
  $(this).stop().animate({ margin: "0", width: '25%', zIndex: '0'}, 150);
});
```

Fiddle for this question -> https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/903535/ .
Inside I have 2 divs (divLeft, divRight). Hover breaks when User clicks with touchpad over divRight like this :
Touchpad "tap" - breaks .hover() after one click
Touchpad LMB click - breaks .hover() after fast click couple of times.

All works fine with external PC mouse.

I have this bug on Chrome and Opera, Firefox works fine.

Thanks for all help.

Comment: Why not just do this in CSS and avoid the problem completely? https://jsfiddle.net/hporxtjL/ Also note that you have left and right the wrong way around.

Comment: Well you wrote that in first 30 sec after I posted this question, before I changed my Fiddle to [link](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/896226/). And I got the same bug on your fiddle when I click with laptop touchpad.